# How to Validation a true/original type of a file

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node.js, multer

Technologies used:

Frontend: React js
Backend: Nodejs
Database: MSSQL Server

API Calls: axios

I have a created a application where I am uploading a profile image and that image I am storing in backend using multer.

**The Backend Code with Multer:**

```
const imageConfig = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: (req, file, callback) => {
        callback(null, './Config/Uploads/Images')
    },
    filename: (req, file, callback) => {
        const dt = new Date();
        const extname = file.originalname.split('.')
        callback(null, `image-${dt.getDate()}-${dt.getMonth()}-${dt.getFullYear()}-${dt.getTime()}.${extname[extname.length - 1]}`)
    }
})

const imageFilter = (req, file, callback) => {

    if (file.mimetype === 'image/png') {
        callback(null, true)
    }
    else {
        callback(null, false)
    }
}

const uploadImage = multer({
    storage: imageConfig,
    limits: { fileSize: '2048000' },
    fileFilter: imageFilter
}).single('image')
```

- With the above code I am able to check the type, but the actual problem is **When I change an .exe file to .png and try to upload it**, it is validating it as png and not saying any errors.

So, **If you guys know any solution please share with me**

---

I have tried below packages and both of them are asking for path, but I want to check the validation before I upload that in server. As the file data which we will get from the client side will not be a path.

**Package1:** npm i image-parser

**Package2:** npm i parse-image

Comment: _"but I want to check the validation before I upload that in server"_ - no you don't (at least not _only_ there), because then I could still make the corresponding request myself, circumventing any "validation" you might have implemented.

Comment: But for _extra_ client-side validation before the upload happens, you could read the file content as a data URI, and assign it as src of an image element - and listen for the `error` event that will fire, when the browser _can_ display the file as an image.